# How can I extract a single element from a list into a data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I compiled a list of ~60 data frames to keep my RStudio environment tidy.

I will need to occasionally extract a single element into a data frame so that I can work on it before putting it back into the list - how can this extract be achieved?

I am aware that I can manipulate the list element directly, but that isn't ideal and being able to extract the data frame would serve me better for my needs.

Comment: If `dflist` is your list of dataframes, `df <- dflist[[n]]`, work on `df`, then `dflist[[n]] <- df`

Comment: Perfect! If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `dflist` is your list of dataframes, then the easiest way to work on element `n` would be something like

```
df <- dflist[[n]]
#...work on df...then
dflist[[n]] <- df
```